# Saving a file returned by web-service in java

Tags: java, web-services

I have to make a call to a web-service for which the response is as per following

```
<ns2:wsresponse>
    <ns2:length>10582</ns2:length>
    <ns2:filecontent>H4sIAAAAAAAAALVZa3OjSLL9fB...    
    (Snip)
    </ns2:filecontent>
    <ns2:contentType>application/gzip</ns2:contentType>
</ns2:wsresponse>
```

The web-service is actually returning a file which is encoded using mime-type application/gzip (as in ns2:contentType). I am not sure how to save the file on disk on the client side in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ns2:filecontent>` tag appears to hold a BASE64 encoded string which probably is the content of the file.

Basically take that BASE64 encoded string decode it and the resulting byte[] can be used to store the data on disk.